# Correct way to run async method synchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a class inheriting an interface where a `GetArticle` method is defined as `async`. One of the implementing classes uses an `await` inside the implementation but another class does not need the await and runs synchronously but the method signature still has the `async` keyword.

What's the correct way to implement the latter, sync method so it doesn't show the "Method will run synchronously" warning?

```
public async Task<Article> GetArticle(int articleId)
{
    return _articles.Where(a => a.ArticleId == articleId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: The `async` / `await` keywords don't matter. The real question is "does your method need to return a `Task` or `Task<T>`?" In addition, the normal naming convention is to add "Async" to the end of the method name if it returns a Task.

Comment: This method definitely needs to return an object so I do need `Task<T>`

Comment: The `async` keyword is an implementation detail. It's not part of any method's signature.

Comment: So I can skip it in the implementation?

Comment: @Val a better question would be why? Why do you want this? If the caller expects the method to *not* block, this method will cause serious problems. This isn't about the needs of the method but the needs of the *caller*. It's OK to `return Task.FromResult` in a mock object but would freeze the UI if you tried to filter lots of data in production. Besides, if the data is already in memory, why not turn `_articles` into a `Dictioanry<int,Article>` so you can use `_articles.TryGetValue(articleId,out var article)` ? Dictionary lookups are very fast even for a lot of data

Comment: Sorry, you lost me there. Why what? I want to exchange classes implementing the interface. One class calls a database and uses `await`. Another class uses a memory object and doesn't need to `await`. The caller should be agnostic of which class is being used so the caller always `await`s. I believe because of this I need to have the `async` on both implementations. Hence my question about what is the correct way.

Comment: This is about the *caller*, not the method. The caller expects no blocking because the method said it won't block when it returned a Task. Scanning all items in a large list can be slow enough to cause problems and gets slower the more items you have. You can use `Dictionary<long,Article>` to avoid this problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think if the list was really huge, the OP would have wrapped the call into a `Task.Run()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue if you have to implement an interface that you can't change. Just remove the async keyword and call `Task.FromResult`. If the synchronous version was a `void`, you would return `Task.CompletedTask`.

You should also wrap the content of your method into a try/catch block. In the catch-block, you should return `Task.FromException`, otherwise you could get unexpected behaviour when you await the method.

```
public Task<Article> GetArticle(int articleId)
{
    try
    {
        var article = _articles.Where(a => a.ArticleId == articleId).FirstOrDefault();
        return Task.FromResult(article);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Task.FromException<Article>(e);
    }
}
```

Example if method was void:

```
public Task DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I did something");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Task.FromException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be a nasty surprise for everyone expecting the method to be asynchronous. It's OK to use this in test dummies but not in production if the operation can take a while

Comment: When you have to do this then the problem is not actually in your code, but in the mind of the software architect.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is only a nasty surprise if it takes a long time. Maybe `_articles` is a list with just 10 entries?

Comment: What about exception handling?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Just use try/catch. I don't see any problem? https://dotnetfiddle.net/KLFhRm

Comment: Here is the problem: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x80R61

Comment: In an asynchronous method, convention follows that any exception thrown should be placed on the returned `Task`, not thrown directly.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thank you for the hint. I extended the answer.